# Bully Algorithm - Detecting Failure

Tags: algorithm, bully-algorithm

Descriptions of the bully algorithm usually do not cover the actual detection of a failure.

I have a working implementation of the bully algorithm that uses the elections themselves to detect failures, rather than have failures trigger elections.

In short, elections in my implementation are performed on a scheduled basis, rather than upon a failure detection.

Clearly this means network traffic is generated, but it seems like a simple solution to something that otherwise might become complicated (e.g. having a separate failure detection mechanism, which will have its own network traffic).

Can anyone see a problem with this?

Comment: Bully algorithm assumes the system is synchronous and uses timeout for identifying process failure. -Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_algorithm

Comment: OK, so what triggers the elections (since the timeout occurs as part of an election)? Put another way, assume all nodes are OK and an election has been performed. When will the next election occur?

Comment: I don't see a major problem with this but I also wouldn't describe it as a bully algorithm, it's too much of a modification. Also, depending on what your election schedule is, is there a risk that a new process with a higher ID comes online between elections? How do you decide how often to schedule elections?

Comment: @Vicky, please can you help me with my question in my comment above yours?

Comment: @Ben, does the question in your comment relate to the "standard" bully algorithm? In that case, if all nodes are OK and an election has been performed, another election won't be performed until another node comes on line (or one of the existing nodes fails).

Comment: I see, so my understanding is correct then. The bully algorithm assumes the presence of a separate failure detection mechanism. My approach of simply scheduling frequent elections would appear to provide the failure detection mechanism implcitly. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, I am focused on the textbook bully algorithm and how it relates to my choice of failure detection implementation.

Comment: @Vicky "Also, depending on what your election schedule is, is there a risk that a new process with a higher ID comes online between elections?" When a new process comes online between elections, it immediately holds an election. "How do you decide how often to schedule elections?" Great question, I just chose a timespan small enough that failures and new nodes were promoted and demoted in a "reasonable" time.

Comment: @Ben, OK, I see. That sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume there are 4 nodes A, B, C and D in your distributed system. Let us assume the current leader is A. An election occurs only if any one of the nodes B, C or D identifies that the coordinator A is not responding. The failure of the leader A is understood because of message timeouts or failure of the coordinator to initiate a handshake. Unlike your algorithm in the standard bully algorithm the elections are performed only in case of coordinator failure or when a new node with  a higher process id is introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the leader election is started when a member *suspect* that there is no leader anymore, i.e. after a (local) timeout.
Frequently, a local timeout is not sufficient, but in addition an expected action of the leader.

Appling this scheme, there is no need for a periodic re-election nor for a special failure detection.

Comment: By "a local timeout" you mean that elections are often held automatically after a pre-defined period to "check on the state of the world"? Clearly other triggers for elections could be implemented (e.g. when known failures are communicated to candidate nodes).

Comment: Well, that is what I referred as "expected action" of the leader. For other node failures (except the leader), one do not need a new election.